# How to make contents of a html page smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html page with tables and texts. How do I make all the content smaller without breaking any form ?

I tried this css but it breaks the form of the table, so the header of table overlapped.

```
body{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.67);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.67);
    transform: scale(0.67);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a matter of reducing font size, padding and margins?

Comment: Perhaps you should include a sample code so we could better understand what's going wrong, but yeah, it should most likely be a matter of font size.

Comment: Of course I used padding and margin, but for table with sheet border. Inside tables I did not use any padding and margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
body {
   zoom: 90%;
}
```

It depends on the way you set your content, but it might work.

Note: this doesn't work very well in Firefox (https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom)

Comment: fast and furious. Thanks a lot! It works very well. :)